# Print output in text file in Python - Newline issue

Tags: printing, python-2.7

Hi I am having problem with print the output in a text file.
Suppose, I have an array

> A=[ [1,2,3],
>         [4,5,6],
>         [7,8,9] ]

I have the code :

```
       for i in A:
         for j in i:              
            print(j),
         print ""
```

it will print

```
      1 2 3
      4 5 6
      7 8 9
```

now I have the code to print the same output in a text file

```
    for i in A:
    for j in i:
        print >> file,j
        print(j),

    print ""
    print >> file,""
```

but this is not writing the same previous console output in the file. How can I write the same output ??
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try the below code?
It should work as you want it to

```
A=[ [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9] ]

f = open('myfile','w')

for i in A:
    for j in i:    
        print(j),
        f.write(str(j) + ' ')
    f.write("\n")

f.close()
```